# Circle button dynamic size android

Tags: android, button, dynamic, size, geometry

I'm developing an app that requires circle buttons, I achieved the expected result, like this image:

[image]

The problem is that I need to set a fixed value to the width and height to get the correct shape, otherwise the buttons would be like the following image and I needed it to be dynamic:

[image]

My button's XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_ab_mais"
    style="@style/TipoSanguineoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:text="@string/pedir_doacao_sangue_ab_mais"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The button's background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <solid android:color="@color/branco" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <solid android:color="@color/cinza_tablayout" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: First problem I see is the layout_weight, this will override the wrap_content.

Comment: I have tried without the layout_weight, but the same problem occurs

Comment: You can also set height and width inside your item. This will mostly set a ration, not an absolute size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, I just needed to create a custom button, where I override the `onMeasure` method, like this:

```
public class CircleButton extends Button {
    public CircleButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

The button's XML:

```
<br.org.component.CircleButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_b_menos"
    style="@style/TipoSanguineoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:text="@string/pedir_doacao_sangue_b_menos"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```